# Поделить URL на условные части

Tags: php

Пример URL - `http://main.easy.ru/bistro-zaymi-na-kartu-sberbanka-v-biyske/srochniy-zaym-onlayn-v-jeleznogorske.html`

Его нужно разделить на условные части в виде `сабдомен(main)||категория(bistro-zaymi-na-kartu-sberbanka-v-biyske)||страница(srochniy-zaym-onlayn-v-jeleznogorske.html)`

Думал и мутил как-то с `explode()`,разделяя - но получалось нелепо.

Прошу помочь мне в составление алгоритма разделения на эти условные части.

**Для чего это нужно?**

Так организовано ЧПУ.И именно так кажется проще мне.Иногда URL может не содержать либо ссылки страницы,которая запрашивается или `сабдомена`.

Answer (score 1):

Вам отлично подойдет функция:
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-url.php

А уже сам ЧПУ путь можно делить с помощью explode